# How do I run node js restify application in debug mode in vs code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, restify

I am unable to run node js restify with typescript application in vs code.

I need to debug the application for checking async call in my application.

I tried with node js debug launch.json file, but I couldn't able to run the application. It doesn't start itself.

Comment: did you follow the [docs](http://restify.com/docs/home/)? perhaps you *did something wrong™*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have followed with docs, but unfortunately There is no much information for doing debug option in VS code for restify application.

Comment: I want to run restify with typescript application in debug mode to analyze the async call happening in it.